# ¿Como puedo validar fecha con DataAnnotation con formato dia-mes-año?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tengo un problema con DataAnnotation  en cuanto a la validación.
quiero que la fecha seleccionada tenga el formato dia-mes año. todo anda bien, excepto por la validacion de DataAnnotation.
Este es mi modelo:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Complete este Campo")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")] 
public DateTime? FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
```

Esta es mi Vista:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FechaNacimiento, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Fecha Nacimiento" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FechaNacimiento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button> 



<script>
$(function ($) {
    $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {

        closeText: 'Cerrar',
        prevText: '<Ant',
        nextText: 'Sig>',
        currentText: 'Hoy',
        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
});
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Coloque  esto en el webconfig:

```
<globalization uiCulture="es-AR" culture="es-AR" />
```

Sin embargo cuando le doy clic al botón submit me lanza el siguiente error:
    " El campo FechaNacimiento debe ser una fecha."
[image: DataAnnotation mensaje error]

Comment: Hola, te recuerdo que el formato de fecha que indicas que se valide en el modelo, solo funciona en los métodos del Helper '@Html.EditorFor' y en '@Html.DisplayFor'. También has probado hacer @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TuDATE, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"

Comment: Hola Sergio, Si los probé, el tema es que no me reconoce el datepicker. Anda bien con el texboxfor, el tema es esa validación, que al parecer es un tema de los dataanotations.

Comment: Prueba esto @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TuDATE, new { @class = "datepicker"});

Comment: probe esto:                         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FechaNacimiento ,  new { htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control  datepicker", placeholder = "Fecha Nacimiento"} } )  pero no me trae la fecha desde base de datos. nose porque, en el campo value(de la pagina en ejecucion)aparece el valor pero no en el input

Comment: Has probado con otros navegadores? hay algunos navegadores (como el Chrome) que la validación solo la hace en formato fecha ingles.

Comment: Alguien pudo encontrar una solución definitiva a este problema?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba en vez de tener un textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FechaNacimiento, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Fecha Nacimiento" })
```

con un EditorFor:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FechaNacimiento, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Fecha Nacimiento" })
```

Creeria que el error se te presenta porque al tenerlo dentro del textbox le estas diciendo al campo que recibira un texto y el espera un tipo de dato diferente, por eso el validation te marca el error, prueba y me comentas hermano.

Answer (score 0):

El error está en el formato del datepicker

```
dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy'
```

Y la fecha que estás proporcionando maneja 4 digitos para el año.

Saludos

Comment: si, probe tambien con eso, pero el problema viene del lado de las validaciones de dataanotation. saludos.

Answer (score 0):

tambien tenia el mismo error y con lo ultimo que pusiste me salio bien..
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FechaNacimiento , new { htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control datepicker"} })
 y me recupera de la base de datos.. tenia ese error por dias.. y el formato de hora no me validaba el modelo .. en si cambio la apariencia tambien de mi datapicker pero es lo de menos.. probaba con la internazionalicacion y demas y es parece algo de Html5 
en el modelo lo valide diferente 
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
espero que resuelvas el problema

Answer (score 0):

Debes colocar el decorado de expresión regular y darle una expresión que solo permita fechas en formato, en este caso, dia/mes/año. Saludos.

```
[RegularExpression("/^([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(\/|-)([0][1-9]|[1][0-2])\2(\d{4})$/")]
public DateTime? FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
```